# Javascript in PHP in Javascript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP file that contains a javascript function. This function takes "user" as a parameter. How can I include this parameter in embedded PHP?

```
$("#items-table").html("<p><?php echo(hello " + user + "); ?></p>")
```

The error I get is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Must I result to appending to the html in separate chunks?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, because PHP runs on the server, before the Javascript is being sent to the server. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: It is doable, but as Pekka says there's probably no point in doing it. Large-scale dynamically generated Javascript is also not the best idea.

Comment: This function will be called by an ajax function that loads data that requires processing by PHP. What's a better strategy to accomplish this? I'm trying to reload a view based on a new query to the database.

Comment: So you're trying to get `<?php echo(hello " + user + "); ?>` parsed by PHP when you submit the AJAX request?

Comment: Yes. In order to use AJAX, I need a callback function in js, right? I imagine the js function will return a string that contains data processed in PHP.

Comment: Perhaps I should rely on the $_REQUEST objects sent by the ajax request, use those to process the data, and then echo the desired HTML containing that data, and my ajax callback will just set the div's inner HTML. No js in this AJAX request needed?

Comment: @RosePerrone: I 'm not sure I understood, but your comment just above describes how it's normally done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language, and JavaScript is client side. The only way to achieve what you are trying to accomplish is to run the page and first have PHP process what it needs, then send the page to the client, and have the client process what he or she needs.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer My question exactly. ;)

Comment: Although I didn't downvote, the original answer and even the edited version don't really answer the question so the upvotes make less sense to me than the downvotes.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because people assume it doesn't answer the question, even though it does. They're too focused on the OP's wording, instead of his/her intent. (For the record: I upvoted, since the OP's comment makes this answer correct.)

Comment: Yes, this answer seems to correctly clear up with the askers fundamental misunderstanding how PHP and Javascript work.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#items-table").html("<p><?php echo "hello $user"); ?></p>")
```

if variable is in php side

```
$("#items-table").html("<p><?php echo "hello"; ?> + user + " </p>")
```

if variable is in client side, but you wanna say hello with php

Comment: These downvotes just aren't making sense... It's a fantastic answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to influence your javascript with php on the serverside, before sending it to the client for evaluating by the browser, although i would advise against it and try to work with ajax instead.

If you do want to work like this, your code sample should look more like this:

```
$("#items-table").html("<p><?php echo("hello " . $user); ?></p>");
```

This is under the assumption that $user is a variable you have set somewhere else in your php script. The error points to the fact that you are missing the $-sign required for all variables in php. Now the php compiler thinks `user` is a constant, explaining the error message...

Comment: Thanks. The user is a parameter to the js function.